# How can I get the Unicode value of a character in go?

Tags: string, go, unicode, type-conversion

I try to get the unicode value of a string character in Go as an Int value.

I do this:

```
value = strconv.Itoa(int(([]byte(char))[0]))
```

where char contains a string with one character.

That works for many cases. It doesn't work for umlauts like ä, ö, ü, Ä, Ö, Ü.

E.g. Ä results in 65, which is the same as for A.

How can I do that?

Supplement: I had two problems. The first was solved with any of the answers below. The second was a bit more tricky. My input was not Go normalized UTF-8 code, e.g. umlauts were represented by two characters instead of one. As ANisus said the solution is found in the package golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm. The line above is now two lines:

```
rune, _ := utf8.DecodeRune(norm.NFC.Bytes([]byte(char)))
value = strconv.Itoa(int(rune))
```

Any hints to make this shorter welcome ...

Comment: `utf8.DecodeRuneInString(norm.NFC.String(stringSource))` or `utf8.DecodeRune(norm.NFC.Bytes(byteSliceSource))` depending of if your real input is a `string` or a `[]byte`. Avoid unnecessary conversions between byte slices and strings as they can cause copies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strings are utf8 encoded, so to decode a character from a string to get the `rune` (unicode code point), you can use the [`unicode/utf8`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#DecodeRuneInString) package.

**Example:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    str := "AÅÄÖ"

    for len(str) > 0 {
        r, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(str)
        fmt.Printf("%d %v\n", r, size)

        str = str[size:]
    }
}
```

**Result:**

> 65 1
>   197 2
>   196 2
>   214 2

**Edit:** (To clarify Michael's supplement)

A character such as `Ä` may be created using different unicode code points:

*Precomposed:* `Ä` (U+00C4)
*Using combining diaeresis:* `A` (U+0041) + `¨` (U+0308)

In order to get the precomposed form, one can use the normalization package, `golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm`. The NFC (Canonical Decomposition,
followed by Canonical Composition) form will turn U+0041 + U+0308 into U+00C4:

```
c := "\u0041\u0308"
r, _ := utf8.DecodeRune(norm.NFC.Bytes([]byte(c)))
fmt.Printf("%+q", r) // '\u00c4'
```

Comment: Yes, that works if I use a constant assignment, e.g. str := "Ä". Then the length is 2 and the byte codes are [195 132], that results in a Rune: 196. But I read the character from a file, the length is 3 and I get byte codes [65 204 136] and Rune: 65. fmt.Println outputs both strings as Ä. I don't know how the file is encoded.

Comment: It is UTF8 allright, but you have A (U+0040) and a combining diaeresis (¨) character (U+0308). Combined they become Ä. What you need to do is first normalizing your string to NFC form using the `golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm` package.

Comment: I added the solution code to my question above. Feel free to add it to your answer. Most people will look there for it ;-)

Comment: @Michael I modified the reply to include the normalization part. Just a note: normalization isn't Go-specific - it is part of the unicode standard. The `norm` package simply implements unicode normalization.

Answer (score 8):

The "character" type in Go is the [`rune`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types) which is an alias for `int32`, see also [Rune literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals). A `rune` is an integer value identifying a Unicode code point.

In Go `string`s are represented and stored as the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence of the text. The `range` form of the `for` loop iterates over the `rune`s of the text:

```
s := "äöüÄÖÜ世界"
for _, r := range s {
    fmt.Printf("%c - %d\n", r, r)
}
```

Output:

```
ä - 228
ö - 246
ü - 252
Ä - 196
Ö - 214
Ü - 220
世 - 19990
界 - 30028
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/UHKKeGp0q_).

Read this blog article if you want to know more about the topic:

[**Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go**](http://blog.golang.org/strings)

Answer (score 6):

you can use the `unicode/utf8` package

```
rune,_:=utf8.DecodeRuneInString("Ä")
fmt.Println(rune)
```