# How do I encode string in Golang so that it is ASCII?

Tags: go, unicode

I need to replace characters like ampersands, etc into unicode like so:

```golang
func Convert(input string) string {
  // what do I do here?
}

Convert("My & Test") => "My \u0026 Test"
```

Comment: What makes & special? Do you want to "convert" `.` or `+` too? What about `-`? Why not `X`?

Comment: It seems you are more likely looking for Unicode. ASCII would be just a plain number, to my knowledge. Either way, I think you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29161443/9841416)